# how to append a json to another json base on the same id?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, merge

I need to append or merge a multiple json to json that will be main/parent json that will pass to apps that need to use it.

I need to append this json based on "ID".

json1

```
{
    {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"testname1",
        "class":"testclass1"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"testname2",
        "class":"testname2"
    }
}
```

json2

```
{
    {
        "id":"1",
        "json1id":"1",
        "semester1math":"90",
        "semester1science":"80",
        "semester1history":"85"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "json1id":"1",
        "semester2math":"88",
        "semester2science":"75",
        "semester2history":"80"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "json1id":"1",
        "semester3math":"90",
        "semester3science":"95",
        "semester3history":"85"
    },
    {
        "id":"4",
        "json1id":"2",
        "semester1math":"80",
        "semester1science":"80",
        "semester1history":"90"
    },
    {
        "id":"5",
        "json1id":"2",
        "semester2math":"75",
        "semester2science":"86",
        "semester2history":"82"
    },
    {
        "id":"6",
        "json1id":"2",
        "semester3math":"78",
        "semester3science":"85",
        "semester3history":"100"
    },
}
```

I need to combine it to the structure below. I already tried to use JOIN directly to `cursor.execute` but that is not the json structure that I want.

```
{
    {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"testname1",
        "class":"testclass1",
        "marks":{
                    "id":"1",
                    "json1id":"1",
                    "semester1math":"90",
                    "semester1science":"80",
                    "semester1history":"85"
                },
                {
                    "id":"2",
                    "json1id":"1",
                    "semester2math":"88",
                    "semester2science":"75",
                    "semester2history":"80"
                },
                {
                    "id":"3",
                    "json1id":"1",
                    "semester3math":"90",
                    "semester3science":"95",
                    "semester3history":"85"
                }       
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"testname2",
        "class":"testname2",
        "marks":{
                    "id":"4",
                    "json1id":"2",
                    "semester1math":"80",
                    "semester1science":"80",
                    "semester1history":"90"
                },
                {
                    "id":"5",
                    "json1id":"2",
                    "semester2math":"75",
                    "semester2science":"86",
                    "semester2history":"82"
                },
                {
                    "id":"6",
                    "json1id":"2",
                    "semester3math":"78",
                    "semester3science":"85",
                    "semester3history":"100"
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use the correct JOIN and then you wouldn't need to manipulate the JSON strings afterwards?

Comment: i'm sorry but how to JOIN the tables that give output same as the json that i show in the last question above?. I'd used query `SELECT * FROM json1 JOIN json2 ON json2.json1id = json1.id` . But it will give the output with 6 data. it will repeat json1 data. I want to print only single json1 data with new key that contain json2 data and merge it with the same id between the two. I'm sorry for the rough question and explanation.

Comment: how you can save json1, json2 to var python without format key, value. It seem json1 is list object such as `[ {}, {}]`

Answer (score 0):

I refer you to use `join` for resolving the problem. Because you dont show your query to explain. I 'll answer from your two json.

```
json1 = [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"testname1",
        "class":"testclass1"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"testname2",
        "class":"testname2"
    }
]
json2 = [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "json1id":"1",
        "semester1math":"90",
        "semester1science":"80",
        "semester1history":"85"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "json1id":"1",
        "semester2math":"88",
        "semester2science":"75",
        "semester2history":"80"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "json1id":"1",
        "semester3math":"90",
        "semester3science":"95",
        "semester3history":"85"
    },
    {
        "id":"4",
        "json1id":"2",
        "semester1math":"80",
        "semester1science":"80",
        "semester1history":"90"
    },
    {
        "id":"5",
        "json1id":"2",
        "semester2math":"75",
        "semester2science":"86",
        "semester2history":"82"
    },
    {
        "id":"6",
        "json1id":"2",
        "semester3math":"78",
        "semester3science":"85",
        "semester3history":"100"
    },
]

for j1 in json1:
    map_json = list(filter(lambda j2: j2["json1id"] == j1["id"], json2))
    j1.update({"marks": map_json})
print(json1)
```